flutter location package issue not able to solve the error
enter image description herenot able to solve this error.
i tried all the solutions changing gradle setting andriod ios keys but still not able to solve this.
please help me with this. I also this exactly the same as told in pub.dev but still not able to get over it

Your screen shot doesn't show any imports, are you importing the location package?  It would be better if you'd post the actual code rather than an image.

have you imported the package?

Add the import statement at the top: import 'package:location/location.dart';

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

first, check your pubspec.yaml
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  location: ^4.3.0

The initialization is like this:
Location location = new Location();

Then, use these commands to clean your build:
flutter clean
flutter pub get

Hope that will help you!
